# D3 select specific node by data

Tags: d3.js

**Scenario**

I have a D3 tree drawn with 4 nodes. I want to select a node by its data -> uuid

**Current Solution**

```
console.log(
  Object.keys(d3.selectAll('.node-circle').filter(d => d.data.id == '55ac64b257c14bbf9d7525cf0b095f60'))
)
console.log(Object.keys(d3.select('.node-circle').datum()))
```

The second console.log returns `['data', 'height', 'depth', 'parent', 'x', 'y', 'id', 'x0', 'y0']` , while the first returns `['_groups', '_parents']`

**Question**

How can I get the same data from the filtered nodes as from the single-selected node?

Comment: Posting the rest of your code would help a lot! Also `selectAll` [works different than select](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5369146).

Comment: Yeah, I realized after I did that that `selectAll` wasn't just as `select` array, unfortunately. I don't think I can post much more of the code, but what specifically do you think would be helpful to see if I can post that?

Comment: Maybe just how your nodes are added. You can also in your `selectAll` do `d3.selectAll().each(function(d){console.log(d);})` That will console log each selections data. `.each` will run for each node in the selection.

Comment: How do I return the data in the `each` for specifically one node? Additionally, the tree is almost identical to the [Collapsible tree diagram in v4](https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/43a860bc0024792f8803bba8ca0d5ecd) example

Comment: What are you trying to do with the data? Depending on how you are doing things, you could also set the nodes `class` or `id` to `d.data.id` and do `d3.select("#chosenid").datum()`

Comment: I want to perform a test on a specific node by selecting from all the nodes, the node that has an id of 55ac64b257c14bbf9d7525cf0b095f60

Answer (score 3):

Surely it's just combining the two approaches you have, filter the nodes to the id you want and then return its datum?

```
var yourAnswer = d3.selectAll(".node-circle")
    .filter(function(d) { 
        return d.data.id == '55ac64b257c14bbf9d7525cf0b095f60';
    })
    .datum()
;
```

Answer (score 2):

Going off what @mgraham suggested. [According to the docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_filter), you could also do this. Will get the data from only the selection that meets the boolean.

```js
var selectionData = d3.selectAll(".node-circle")
  .select(function(d, i) { return d.data.id == '55ac64b257c14bbf9d7525cf0b095f60' ? this : null; }).datum();
```

Comment: This looks very interesting, I hadn't seen it before. I'll play with it and see if it solves the issue. Thanks!

Comment: I hadn't either actually until now. I find all sorts of new things helping out!

Comment: I would like to know how my answer could be improved? Why was it downvoted?

Comment: I agree, it doesn't help much to downvote and not post a reason

Comment: @H.Trujillo also, I checked this morning and both methods posted as answers will return the same result. I'm thinking that may be a reason.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I'll check it out when I get a chance.

Comment: wasn't me :-) i got a downvote on my answer too, dunno why, someone in a bad mood